# Convert two unidirectional sums to bidirectional sum.

Tags: calculus, summation

If we let $ \alpha = \frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}$  given the sum $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\Big(\frac{1}{k +\alpha} + \frac{1}{k + \bar{\alpha}} \Big )$$ how can I rewrite the sum as $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt3}{2}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $\alpha =-\frac12 +i\frac{\sqrt3 }{2}$, and $\bar \alpha=-\frac12 -i\frac{\sqrt3 }{2}$, $\alpha =-1-\bar \alpha$.

Hence, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k + \bar{\alpha}}& =-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k-\bar \alpha}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k-1-\bar \alpha}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{0}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k+ \alpha}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k+\alpha}+\frac{1}{k+\bar \alpha}\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+\alpha}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And Happy Holidays!  -Mark